# Try and catch for InputMismatchException handling. I want to create TicTacToe game, that can be played with console

Tags: java

Found a solution in here how to properly handle "InputMismatchException" and implemented it to my code. But the result is still not what I expected.

I have to scan for 2 integers (x, y coordinates) and add them to array. Tried to create two loops for x and y separately but, result is the same.

```
    private static void enterCoordinate(char[][] layoutMatrix) {
        int[] xy = new int[2];
        boolean again = true;
        while (again) {
            try {
                System.out.print("Enter the coordinates: ");
                for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                    xy[i] = scanner.nextInt();
                }
                again = false;
            }
            catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println();
                System.err.println("You should enter numbers!");
                scanner.next();
            }
        }
```

output is like below

[image: this is what i see in console]

This is not that result what I want to see

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `nextInt()` fails, it *doesn't* consume the failed token... so you'll recurse, immediately call `nextInt()` again, and that will fail too... so you'll recurse again, etc, forever.

You should probably call `scanner.next()` on failure, to consume the "token that wasn't a number". Just adding that line would probably fix the problem, but I'd suggest you *also* convert this into a `while` loop instead... I don't see any benefit in recursing here (and you could still end up with a stack overflow if the user enters *lots* of invalid numbers).

Comment: how to say while that it should keep asking if there is exception??

Comment: @AnsaganIslamgali: I would probably write a method *just* for asking for a number, that contains a `while (true)` loop with `return scanner.nextInt();` in it. So if it catches an exception, it just goes to the next iteration. But it depends - if you want to start with a new x value if the user makes a mistake with the y value, that approach wouldn't work. A `while(true)` loop in general is probably the way to go, breaking out of the loop on success.